# Force Maven to use latest dependency among the ones present in dependency tree

Tags: maven

I understand Maven's behavior whenever it finds more than one version of the same dependency is to choose the one closer to the dependency root. If more than one are same as close, then it will choose the first one it finds.

Is there a way to change this behavior and make it simply pick the highest version?

Answer (score 1):

The [versions](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) plugin can do some of the work for you, by rewriting your POM, but I ***highly*** recommend avoiding using it.  Explicitly managing dependencies as gogstad and Michael stated is the recommended path.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency management section and pick the version you actually want to use.  You should always be setting versions so you're getting repeatable builds.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to change the maven dependency mechanism to anything other than nearest definition.

If you experience that maven chooses the wrong dependency, the only way to fix it is to explicitly depend on that dependency in your application (maven will of course not allow two different versions of the same dependency in the clasdpath at the same time). The dependency you define will be used in any transitive dependencies for the same artifact.